# Upload de imagens com manipulação usando WideImage

Tags: php, upload, multiple-file-upload, redimensionamento

Boa noite!
Gostaria de realizar o upload de no máximo 5 imagens e ao mesmo tempo manipula-las com a biblioteca WideImage. Porém com o código feito até o momento apenas o upload está funcionando. Estou utilizando a biblioteca pela primeira vez, por isso não tenho tanta experiência... Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.
Desde já agradeço!

```
    $images = $_FILES['fotos'];
    $name = $images['name']; //Atribui uma array com os nomes dos arquivos à variável
    $tmp_name = $images['tmp_name']; //Atribui uma array com os nomes temporários dos arquivos à variável
    $allowedExts = array(".gif", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"); //Extensões permitidas
    $data_dir = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s");
    mkdir("fotos_noticia/" . $data_dir, 0777);
    $dir = 'fotos_noticia/' . $data_dir . "/";
    $img = array();
    $i = 0;

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($tmp_name); $i++) {
        $ext = strtolower(substr($name[$i], -4));
        if (in_array($ext, $allowedExts) && sizeof($tmp_name) <= 5) { //Pergunta se a extensão do arquivo, está presente no array das extensões permitidas
            $new_name = $i . $ext;
            $img[$i] = $new_name;
            $image = \WideImage::load($tmp_name[$i]); //Carrega a imagem utilizando a WideImage
            $image = $image->resize(450, 300, 'outside'); //Redimensiona a imagem para 170 de largura e 180 de altura, mantendo sua proporção no máximo possível
            $image = $image->crop('center', 'center', 450, 300); //Corta a imagem do centro, forçando sua altura e largura
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$i], $dir.$new_name);
```

Comment: antes de mais nada, ja sugiro o uso de outra biblioteca, usei o wide por um tempo

Comment: Pensei nisso mesmo. Me sugere qual? Obs: Só postei porque gostaria de saber se há erro na lógica que usei. Caso identifique me manda um parecer. Valeu!

Comment: https://github.com/gumlet/php-image-resize essa é boa

Comment: Valeu pela dica!